# How to load fontawesome using wordpress customizer checkbox

Tags: wordpress, font-awesome

i am learning to build plugins and i have learnt many things so far. Now i am learning checkboxes. i am building a plugin which loads fontawesome so i have added a setting to wordpress customizer. When i check the checkbox in live customizer all things work perfectly. but when i hit publish it shows 
**Looks like something’s gone wrong. Wait a couple seconds, and then try again.**
It didn't gets published, also when i uncheck it gets saved so means it will not load in frontend.
Also, if i set it to checked by default it doesn't work. below is my code.

```
$wp_customize->add_setting('load_fontawesome_icons', array(
        'default' => 0,
        'sanitize_callback' => 'fontawesome_checkbox'
    ));
    $wp_customize->add_control(new WP_Customize_Control($wp_customize, 'load_fontawesome_icons', array(
        'label' => 'Load Fontawesome Icons',
        'type' => 'checkbox',
        'section' => 'search_submit_section',
        'settings' => 'load_fontawesome_icons'
    )));
    function fontawesome_checkbox($input) {
        if ( true === $input ) {
            add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_fontawesome' );
            function load_fontawesome() {
                wp_enqueue_style( 'fontawesome_icons', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . '/lib/css/fa-solid.min.css' );
            }
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

I am not able to find any solution. thanks in advance

Comment: You've nested the `load_fontawesome` function _inside_ the `fontawesome_checkbox` function.  Pull the `load_fontawesome` function _outside of all other functions_.  This will simplify your problem.

Comment: how will it help. the problem will exist

Comment: Did you try? Have you done any troubleshooting? If you want help, you'll need to receive suggestions and give helpful feedback, otherwise people aren't going to want to help.  And "how it will help" is this: it's bad practice to nest functions inside of other functions in PHP.  It will be cleaner, simpler, easier-to-maintain code.  Put another way: nesting the function has _no value_ in this case, so why do it?

Comment: problem exists after changing nested functions to individual functions.

Comment: thank you problem solved. thank you @cale_b your suggestion worked